# Python MySQL plate number matching with two tables before inserting into another table

Tags: python, mysql

I have 3 Tables.

First is the `Registered Plate Table`

Second is the `Unregistered Plate Table`

Third is the `Vehicle_Login Table`

in Registered Table I have a plate number `AAA4890`

in Unregistered Table I have a plate number `AAA890`

then I have a function that will accept the `recognized plate`.The possible recognition of ocr was `AAA890` and `AAA4890` and etc(which I will dump). Before I insert the `recognized plate` in the `Vehicle_login` I want to compare the `recognized plate` into the plates of `Registered Table and Unregistered table`. If the recognized plate doesn't match the plates with my two tables. I will dump it, otherwise I will insert it into `Vehicle_Login` depending also on which table and it's plates is matched.

Also if the `recognized plate` is already in the `Vehicle_Login` I will not insert it again with this I can prevent multiple values inserting it again. I am reading frames from an Ip cam and every frame my program recognize it.

```
    add_plate = "INSERT INTO vehicle2_login (plate,status,time_login) values (%s,%s,%s)" 
    ts = time.time()
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    last_id = "SELECT * FROM vehicle2_login WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `vehicle2_login`)"
    cursor.execute(last_id)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    last_plate = record[0][1]

    sql = "SELECT * FROM registered where plate = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (plate, ))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    checker = ""
    for row in result_set:
        if plate == row[2]:
            checker = True
        elif plate != row[2]:
            checker = False
        else:
            checker = False

    sql2 = "SELECT * FROM unregistered where plate = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql2, (plate, ))
    result_set2 = cursor.fetchall()
    checker2 = ""
    for row2 in result_set2:
        if plate == row[1]:
            checker2 = True
        elif plate != row[1]:
            checker2 = False
        else:
            checker2 = False
    if checker or not checker2:
        status = "Registered"
        data_plate = (plate,status,st)
        print("This plate number", plate, "is Registered \n")
        if plate == last_plate:
            print("Cannot insert it's already logged in \n")    
        else:
            cursor.execute(add_plate, data_plate)
            mydb.commit()
    elif not checker or checker2:
        status = "Unregistered"
        data_plate = (plate,status,st)
        print("This plate number", plate, "is Unregistered \n")
        if plate == last_plate:
            print("Cannot insert it's already logged in \n")    
        else:
            cursor.execute(add_plate, data_plate)
            mydb.commit()
    elif not checker and not checker2:
        print(plate, "was Dumped!")
```

Comment: Why aren't using LAST_INSERT_ID - or your API's equivalent?

Comment: a function from python?